# Multiple CSS files including the libraries files VS one huge file include all libraries css files

Tags: css

I'm working on a new project and I need to ask about something:
now I have 2 CSS libraries ( Bootstrap + Hover.css ) & I need to load them in addition to ( style.css ) file which contain my styles, so now I have 3 files ( bootstrap.css - hover.css - style.css )

which one is the correct or the best for the website performance and the website speed when the user visit the project website:

1- combine all those 3 files in one huge CSS file and load it ( one request - one file ) ? 
2- load the 3 files every file individually ( 3 requests - 3 files ) ?
3- use a backend solution to combine the 3 files into one file and return it?

also is it deserve to think about it or it's just a 3 small files ?

I'm not talking about the frontend side only but for the backend too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally would stick with 1 minified css file.
BUT in your case both options would be okay.

1 minified file - everything loads at the same time and hopefully the size of the file isn't too large.

3 separate files - when updating your sites CSS then the browser has to re-download only 1 file. bootstrap.css and hover.css would be cached for as long as you have set it on BE side (css changes don't affect them).

Whatever you do. Don't forget to gzip the css :)